# Remove leftover of eclipse package

Tags: uninstall, eclipse

I wanted to reinstall eclipse but I left with some leftovers
[image]
and I don't know how to remove it when I right click I have option of uninstall but when I press it nothing happens

---

Comment: Look for it in the `/usr/share/applications` folder and remove it using `rm the_file_name.desktop` using the terminal, if not there then restart your system and try searching for it in bash.

Comment: I can't find this file.

Comment: Then restart your system and see if it appears in the `dash`.

Comment: It actually was in ~/.local/share/applications.

Comment: That's great glad it was resolved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop `icons` appearing in the `dash` we check for the `.desktop` files in two places:

1. In the `/usr/share/applications` for apps stored system wide for all users.
2. And in `/home/username/.local/share/applications` for applications installed for one user in *their default* home directory or applications that have been *customized* by user
3. Then remove it using two methods from a terminal:

   a. `sudo rm my_icon.desktop` for those found in `/usr/share/applications` folder

   b. `rm my_icon.desktop` for those found in `/home/username/.local/share/applications` directory

   c. In `step b` above you can also do a `right click` and select `move to trash` with your mouse.
4. Then restart your system to have it take effect.